# Is it possible to change object's runtime type by its method?

Tags: java, class

I have two classes:

```
public class Base{

    public Derived becomeDerived(){
         Derived d = new Derived(this);
         //set this pointer pointing to d, 
         //this = d; doesn't work
         return d;
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base{ 
    public Derived(Base b){ }
}
```

Is it possible to change the runtime type of current object by its method as I show in the example?

The reason why I want to do that is providing a method for concatenating objects.

I have

```
public abstract class Table{ 

}
```

and

```
public class ComplexTable extends Table{ }
```

which is in fact a linked-list of `Table` objects.

I would like to provide a method, say `Table.append(Table t)` which not only modify the current Table object, but also make it `ComplexTable`'s instance.

Comment: No, we can't change the type of an object. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I do know. It's impossible. But not *unsolvable* if you tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: @Radiodef updated. So, how do you know that?

Comment: I read the Java Language Specification. On a related note, I would also like a keyword which cooks me breakfast. If there is no JLS which says "there is no keyword which cooks breakfast", does that mean it's not impossible?

Comment: @Radiodef I understand what you mean. All right, I got it.

Comment: @user Ah, in your code `Table` is an `abstract class`, and `abstract class`es can't be instantiated (`Table t = new Table();`), the run-time type of your objects is already `ComplexTable` probably. Unless you have other implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

In your example, `Base` wouldn't become `Derived`, it would return a new `Derived` object.

```
Base foo = new Base();
foo = foo.becomeDerived();
```

This is likely what's throwing you off, remember that the variable is not the object, just a reference to one. So while you can say `foo` changes from `Base` to `Derived`, the run-time type of an *object* didn't change, you made a *new* object with a *different* run-time type and reassigned the variable.

---

***Edit:*** More in depth example. I give the objects "names" just so it's easier to understand.

```
Base foo = new Base();

/* After execution:
 *
 * Vars:   | Objects:
 * foo ----+---> a Base object (Name: Joe)
 */

foo = foo.becomeDerived();

/* After execution:
 *
 * Vars:   | Objects:
 * foo ----+---> a Derived object (Name: Phil)
 *         |     a Base object (Name: Joe)(notice nothing references it)
 */
```

The type of "Joe" did not change. Joe was and will always be a `Base` object. This is what you're referring to by "run-time type of an object." However, the run-time type of **variables** change *all the time!* In this example, `foo` starts as `Base` but becomes `Derived`.

Comment: No no no no no, sir. I want foo become a derived after invoking foo,becomeDerived();

Comment: @user - After executing the above code, `foo instanceof Derived` will be true. Are you talking about something else?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `this` to `d` as `this` is super type of `Derived d`.
But it is possible to store object of type `Derived` like `d` in this case into a reference of Type `Base`.

You can store types of derived classes in reference of base class. But it is not changing types technically just reference holding object of derived type.

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike in C++
>
> You can not change or reassign the value of `this`.

`This` was chosen to be a reserved word.So Answer is

> **No** ,it is not possible to change the runtime type of current object

.

One more error i could find in your code is always use the Base reference variable so you can refer to objects of classes extending it.

```
Base b;
b=new Derived();
b=new Base();
```

Comment: Where did the quote come from?

Comment: `*this = Derived{};` wouldn't work in C++ either, because `Derived` might be larger in memory than `Base`. It is probably UB or slices.

Comment: @Radiodef Java doesnt allow assigning to this at all!

Comment: Yes, I know. But since your quoted text starts with *"unlike in C++"*, I'm just pointing out that it's probably not good in C++ either. (I have a hunch that it slices like `Base b = Derived{};` does, but since I'm not a C++ expert, I can't say for sure.)

Answer (score 0):

**Bad idea follows**

It is possible to change the type of an object, but it relies on behaviour that is not part of the JVM spec and is thus not portable. You have been warned.

There is a class `sun.misc.Unsafe` that let's you read/write memory at any offset of an object. The type of an object is stored in the [object's header](https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/43d6135e8a15798cc46c) at offset 8 on 64-bit JVMs. Thus, to change the type of the object all you need to do is to change the value at this offset. Note that the types/classes your switching between must have the same structure (reference fields on the same offsets and having the same total size). If not, the garbage collector will read non-references as references (or vice-versa) and crash you JVM.

I'm not providing working example intentionally as I'm not recommending this. Stuff like this is more suitable in C than in Java. It's really not that hard to do though, and the link I've provided together contains all information required.

Some tests I made indicates that it works on several JVMs and that the JIT is robust against these dangerous object type changes. That is no promise that it works in all systems and under all conditions.

By the way, I'm curious to hear from someone who can explain why the JIT doesn't consider the type of an object as a jit-compile-time constant, or how the JIT knows to recompile when the type of an object has changed.